# Responsive max-width for div containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a few  tags and would like to get them responsive (maximum browser width) in case of two divs are not placed in one row.

```
<div>
  <div class="card" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="" width=100 alt="logo" />
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Test1</h4>
      <p class="card-text">
        Status: <span class="label label-success">Active</span>
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">Created: 2017-05-12</p>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="" width=100 alt="logo" />
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Test sdf ;ljkgwe;o k5l4j ;l2k54k j9rjg </h4>
      <p class="card-text">
        Status: <span class="label label-success">Active</span>
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">Created: 2017-05-12</p>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="" width=100 alt="logo" />
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Test deg sdkjf glkjsdhg lkjdshfglk jhdsfkg dfg </h4>
      <p class="card-text">
        Status: <span class="label label-success">Active</span>
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">Created: 2017-05-13</p>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1L6pfwm/182/
So all is OK in my JSFiddle example except https://gyazo.com/f5ae57b4969fd55a43e276eaf9429be7 - in this case div's width should be 100%. In other words I won't see huge white gaps in the right of each div.
Is it possible?
Please advice.

Comment: OK so in your 2nd link, you want all 3 divs to stretch to 100% where right now they aren't?

Comment: @Keith, yes you are totally right.

Comment: Add a media query for the width where you want them to be 100% then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex like this:

[edit]Add this to the end of the CSS:

```
@media  (max-width: 700px) {
  .card { flex: 0 0 1; float:none;}
  .card-block {float:left;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1L6pfwm/184/

To fill the height try:

```
@media  (max-width: 700px) {
  .card { flex: 0 0 1; float:none; flex-direction: column;}
  .card-block {float:left;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1L6pfwm/185/

(sorry it looks like it's also stretching the content and not the surrounding div)

[More on stretching vertically here](https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/)

Comment: no, in this case there are white gaps inside each div. I asked just avoid white gaps outside of each div.

Comment: Is it possible to make last div in a row stretched to the end of the browser window?

Answer (score 1):

use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) 
you can control the width depending on your screen size..

http://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/6sod2kb3/

```
@media  (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    width:98%;
  }
}
@media  (min-width: 701px) {
  .card {
    width:48%;
  }
}
```